# How to register and use props correctly in new vue custom element?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I use new future [defineCustomElement](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/web-components.html#definecustomelement) from vue version 3.2.

Code `main.js`:

```
    import { defineCustomElement } from './defineCustomElementWithStyles'
    import App from './App.ce.vue'
    import store from './store'
    import router from './router'
    
    customElements.define(
      'app-root',
      defineCustomElement(App, {
        plugins: [store, router],
      })
    )
```

Code `defineCustomElementWithStyles.js`:

```
import { defineCustomElement as VueDefineCustomElement, h, createApp, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'

const getNearestElementParent = (el) => {
  while (el?.nodeType !== 1 /* ELEMENT */) {
    el = el.parentElement
  }
  return el
}

export const defineCustomElement = (component, { plugins = [] }) =>
  VueDefineCustomElement({
    render: () => h(component),
    setup() {
      const app = createApp()

      // install plugins
      plugins.forEach(app.use)

      app.mixin({
        mounted() {
          const insertStyles = (styles) => {
            if (styles?.length) {
              this.__style = document.createElement('style')
              this.__style.innerText = styles.join().replace(/\n/g, '')
              getNearestElementParent(this.$el).prepend(this.__style)
            }
          }

          // load own styles
          insertStyles(this.$?.type.styles)

          // load styles of child components
          if (this.$options.components) {
            for (const comp of Object.values(this.$options.components)) {
              insertStyles(comp.styles)
            }
          }
        },
        unmounted() {
          this.__style?.remove()
        },
      })

      const inst = getCurrentInstance()
      Object.assign(inst.appContext, app._context)
      Object.assign(inst.provides, app._context.provides)
    },
  })
```

Code `App.ce.vue` where I register and use `prop`:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p>{{ title }}</p>
    <nav>
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <router-view />
    </main>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  props: {
    title: String,
  },
}
</script>
```

Code `index.html` where I set value fro prop `title`:

```html
<app-root title="hello"></app-root>
```

Get error with message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')
```

Full demo project [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-custom-elements-with-plugins-ofjtng)

Comment: In my case I had to use `Object.assign(inst!.appContext.provides, app._context.provides);` to make it work with Vuetify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `App` component is being wrapped in `defineCustomElementWithStyle`, the wrapper's `props` should be passed to `App` within `setup()`.

1. Copy the component's `props` into the wrapper's `props`:
2. Move the wrapper's `render` prop into a return from `setup()`.
3. Pass `setup()`'s `props` argument to the rendering of `App` (`h()` receives `props` as its 2nd argument).

```js
export const defineCustomElement = (component, { plugins = [] }) =>
  VueDefineCustomElement({
    props: component.props, 1️⃣
    // render: () => h(component), 2️⃣
    setup(props 3️⃣) {
      ⋮
      return () => h(component, props 3️⃣)
    }
  })
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-custom-elements-with-styles-zhxyrx?file=src%2FdefineCustomElementWithStyles.js)